# Is there any hadith about dignity and honor?

Tags: hadith

Is there any hadith that gives a condition and if done so then ones dignity and honor will be protected? Like if you do this then Allah will protect your dignity and honor.

Comment: You could check this resource out: https://abuaminaelias.com/dailyhadithonline/tag/dignity-wiqar/

Answer (score -1):

I think this hadeeth has a strong connection to dignity as it speaks of shame
Quoted:

*Narrated Abu Mas`ud:*
*The Prophet (ﷺ) said, 'One of the sayings of the early* *Prophets which the people have got is: If you don't feel* *ashamed (from Haya': pious shyness from committing* *religeous indiscretions) do whatever you like." (See Hadith* *No 690, 691, Vol 4)*
This is a part of another hadeeth
Quoted:

*Abu Huraira reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying:*

*All things of a Muslim are inviolable for his brother in faith: his blood, his wealth and his honour.*
Sahih Muslim 2564 a

Answer (score -1):

> 'Imran Ibn Muslim reported:

There is this following Hadith:

> Umar Ibn Khattab, may Allah be pleased with him, said:

> "Acquire knowledge and teach people. Learn with dignity, humility and tranquility. For those who teach you and for those who you teach. Do not be tyrannical scholars and thus base your knowledge upon ignorance.

> source: Shu'ab al-Iman 1650, grade: authentic

More, in the Qur'an we have the following *ayat*:

> We have certainly honoured the children of Adam.

According to scholars such as al-Qaradawi and al-Shawqani, *al-'Ird*, that is dignity and honour, is so important that they form one of the objectives of *Maqasid al-Shari'ah*, the higher objectives of the Islamic way that Islamic teachings help to protect.